# TextView content in one layout going inside another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

```
 <RealtiveLayout>
    //alignparentstart
<LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

//centerinparent
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView/>
</LinearLayout>

//alignparentend
<LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to make a layout like above.Above layout is a layout for Recyclerview list item.Now after fetching data from backened server if i setText of text view which is in middle then if text is long then it goes inside last one linear layout which is alignparentend.How can i stop this?How can i make sure that text view does not goes inside others layout?

Comment: align the middle LinearLayout to left and right of corresponding left and right linear layouts.

Comment: You can also use [this library](https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview) to auto fit your text into your textView

Comment: post complete code along with image for what your try looks like and what you want

Answer (score 0):

Set the code like this format :

```
<RealtiveLayout>

          <LinearLayout>
          //alignparentstart
          //align parent top true
          </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout>
         //centerinparent
        //Set property layout below top layout (Id of top layout)
        //Set property layout above bottom layout(Id of Bottom layout)

             <TextView
             // set textview property  android:scrollbars = "vertical"
             />

        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout>
          //align parent bottom
          //alignparentend
        </LinearLayout>

</RealtiveLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

please make following changes in your xml file and layout. Use align bottom and top property to solve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llTopLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/llTopLayout"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/llBottomLayout"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llBottomLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```